# Magento 2 Get custom attribute values in phtml

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, catalog, custom-attributes

I want to populate attribute(Gender) values in select dropdown on listing page. On selecting specific value of the gender attribute, the product list should be filtered.

The gender attribute has 3 values

1. Male
2. Female
3. Others

For some products the attribute value is set to male and female as the product is unisex.

I want to know how can I get the values of attributes(male, female, others) irrespective of products.

Comment: Do you want to get the product attribute value on the category page?

Comment: Yes, All values in select dropdown on category page.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the select attribute value for the product with the below code.

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

***Hope this helps!!!***

Answer (score 0):

In block file, Use the following code...

```
protected $eavConfig;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
    ...
)
{
    ...
     $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    ...
}

public function getGenderOptions()
{
    $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'gender'[your attribute code]);
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
    $genderOptions = array();
    foreach ($options as $key => $option) 
    {
        if($option['label'])
        {         
            array_push($gender, $option['label']);
        }
    }
}
```

In the phtml file, Use the following code...

```
$genderOptions = $this->getGenderOptions();    
  foreach ($genderOptions as $option)     
  {        
          print_r($option);    
  }
```

You may see all the options on the category page,After that, you may use it as your wish...

Thanks.